# How Email Sent In Django

Tags: django, email, send

I have setting.py

```
# Email settings
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'email@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'pass'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

and email method is in admin.py

```
send_mail(
            'Subject here',
            'Here is the message.',
            'from@gmail.com',
            ['to@gmail.com'],
            fail_silently=False,
        )
```

but it gives error
`SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.`
How I solve this, working on localhost

Comment: Are you sure about the port number? I used it before with port number = 465

Comment: on 465 Connection unexpectedly closed

Comment: thanks buddy working this port number with EMAIL_USE_SSL = True

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It Works on port 465 and email ssl true

```
EMAIL_PORT = 465
EMAIL_USE_SSL = True
```

Answer (score 2):

try to create a custom send email file like this

```
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

# Send Email Function
def send(to):
    email = EmailMessage()
    email['from'] = 'Test'
    email['to'] = to
    email['subject'] = 'Hello World'

    with smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587) as smtp:
      smtp.ehlo()
      smtp.starttls()
      smtp.login('user', 'password')
      smtp.send_message(email)
```

Answer (score 0):

For TLS:

```py
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```