# SMTP Authentication Error: Username and Password not accepted:

Tags: python, smtp

My email and password are correct but I'm not able to send email using my script.

```
import smtplib
content ="hello"
mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login('mymail@gmail.com','password')
mail.sendmail('mymail@gmail.com','destination@gmail.com',content)
mail.close()
```

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59777016/how-email-sent-in-django) might be helpful

Comment: try with mail = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com",465)

Answer (score -1):

You need a space before and after your credentials, like this:

```
mail.login(' mymail@gmail.com ',' password ')
mail.sendmail(' mymail@gmail.com ',' destination@gmail.com ',content)
```

Then it will work.

Full code example, that runs in a program of mine:

```
emailpassword = ' password ' 
emailsend = ' myemail@gmail.com '
emailreceive = ' destination@gmail.com '

import smtplib
smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
type(smtpObj)
smtpObj.ehlo()
smtpObj.starttls()
smtpObj.login(' myemail@gmail.com ', emailpassword)
smtpObj.sendmail(emailsend, emailreceive, 'Subject: test\nThis is an automated email.')
smtpObj.quit()
```